# How to check if season picked is the correct one based on the month now?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-fragments

I am currently working on an app that asks me what season it is. I have made radio buttons for all four seasons and was just wondering how i'd be able to check that the season they picked is correct based on the month right now. It's on a fragment by the way.

This my code as of right now.

```
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {

private RadioButton choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4;
private int winter,spring,summer,fall;
private RadioGroup radioGroup;
private int season;


public FragmentTwo() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    choice1 = getView().findViewById(R.id.choiceOne);
    choice2 = getView().findViewById(R.id.choiceTwo);
    choice3 = getView().findViewById(R.id.choiceThree);
    choice4 = getView().findViewById(R.id.choiceFour);
    radioGroup = getView().findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
    season = Calendar.MONTH;

    choice1.toString();
    choice2.toString();
    choice3.toString();
    choice4.toString();

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment_two, container, false);


}

}
```

i'm not sure yet where I want to go with this. I'm open for suggestions. What's going on in my mind right now is make an array for each season containing integers for example:

```
summer[] = {11,0,1}
```

thats representing December, January, February.
and then find a way to compare that to season which is the month as of right now.
but then im not sure how i could add that array value to the radiobuttons to check if the end user checked the right season? if that makes sense..

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener to radio group and act when changed:

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
         //create a string array expressing the season each month belongs to
         String monthSeasons[] = {
          "Winter", "Winter", //0,1
          "Spring", "Spring", "Spring",//2,3,4
          "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", //5,6,7
          "Fall", "Fall", "Fall",//8,9,10
          "Winter"//11
          };

        //identify current month
        java.util.Date date= new Date();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        //Verify the current season
        System.out.println("This is the current season:"+ monthSeasons[ month ];
        //now get the season checked and compare

        }
    });
```